# Two separate armatures

Tags: rigging, armature

Can I make two separate armatures by not joining them and make one follow the other just like the *Keep Offset* option.

Comment: Welcome Andrejs!
The bit about the "Keep Offset" option makes me think I might be misunderstanding your question.
Why do you want two separate armatures? What are you using them for?

Comment: I'm Creating 2d Character.  And I would like to Make separate Armatures For Eyes And mouth So I can easy save The poses and while animating save lots of time>.  Also I'M making 2d Character Who is able to tur the head , This means I need to make another armatures for eyes and mouth and that means that there will be so much bones so you can get confused  while rigging because of amount of constrains.  
I mention ''Keep Offset'' Because I want to connect two Separate Armatures same way by not joining them  as one armature. Thanks For you're Question :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that and this is a useful thing to do for example if you want to export an animation to a game engine (have one armature of only deform bones and another armature of only control bones).

There is one tedious slightly step involved:
You have to create a "Child Of" bone constraint (or "Copy Rotation" or whatever fits your use case) for every single bone of your "following" armature to your control armature's corresponding bone.
I recommend using two different armature visualizations and display bone names so you can more easily see what you are working on.
[image: constrain armature to another armature bone by bone]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try this. This is probobly what I was Looking and hoping for :)